# Brute force loop, figuring out a rotation matrix

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm trying to brute force a rotation matrix by using a loop. Basically I have a bunch of points (6 to be exact) in two different coordinate systems, and I want to try a bunch of rotation matrices with different values for euler angles in order to find a match between the points. My BIG problem though is there is also a translation involved in this coordinate transformation. That is the part that is kind of getting me stuck. Here is my attempt

```
%Point 1 (Between two front teeth)
Vector_Endo1 = [-8.9329*voxTommConversion;8.5058*voxTommConversion;117.7193*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint1 = [418.7801;41.3845;231.3922];

%Point 2 (Mid-left skull, portruding bone on bottom)
Vector_Endo2 = [-11.2102*voxTommConversion;112.4456*voxTommConversion;61.3865*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint2 = [444;275.3698;99.7672];

%Point 3 (Cavity on top, front, middle, right of head, pointed section)
Vector_Endo3 = [140.0249*voxTommConversion;95.0548*voxTommConversion;148.9631*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint3 = [79.6156;255.4725;259.3405];

%Point 4 (Between two molars on left side)
Vector_Endo4 = [-9.4742*voxTommConversion;42.4474*voxTommConversion;87.0998*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint4 = [428.7617;118.7252;158.994];

%Point 5 (Left large stub inside of head)
Vector_Endo5 = [42.2453*voxTommConversion;85.6763*voxTommConversion;105.5044*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint5 = [309.3354;221.2764;187.5172];

%Point 6 (Thin portruding point underneath right side of skull)
Vector_Endo6 = [1.3304*voxTommConversion;101.7924*voxTommConversion;157.7978*voxTommConversion];
voxPoint6 = [390.7929;259.3982;311.4098];

allPoints=[Vector_Endo1,Vector_Endo2,Vector_Endo3,Vector_Endo4,Vector_Endo5,Vector_Endo6];

%testVector is used to compare difference between computed offset and real offset
for Rx=0:pi/180:2*pi,
    for Ry=0:pi/180:2*pi,
        for Rz=0:pi/180:2*pi,
            for points = 1:length(allPoints)
                testVector=euler2rotmat(Rx,Ry,Rz)*allPoints(:,points);
                allTestVectors(:,i)=testVector;
```

I think that should give me all the rotation matrices I would ever need (to a certain approximation). I was going to proceed by making some code that finds the rotation matrix that gives THE SMALLEST magnitude different between my test vector and the real points (allPointsVox)....which should be achieved after the rotation matrix. The only problem is that there is an intermediate step of translation between what I have and determining that value.

Any ideas on how to find an approximate translation value between the coordinate systems? I was thinking of averaging over all values to get an average translation but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any other tips are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox then Matlab has this built in: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html if not then google affine image registration algorithms. There are also freely available toolboxes on the FEX that do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the brute force approach instead of just calculating the parameters of the transformation? This is common problem (matching two point clouds and finding the transformation between them) with existing solutions like  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28305-estimaterigidtransform for example

Comment: Just what some guy who has his PHD and has been working in endoscopic technology for 10 years told me to do lol....can't say it's the best method

Comment: Brute force sounds like the worst method to me.

Comment: I knew other methods like the ones you are showing me, but he insists I use loops, I think it has to do with finding error etc....Just if you could help copmlete this rathre than show me other methods. We are well aware of them, in fact I have already downloaded KoordTransform3D which is extremely nice and completes this, but we need other information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract the centroid of the point colouds from each set, thus eliminating the translation effect.

Comment: I wish I could do that! Unfortunately the hard part about this problem is that it is impossible for me to measure that distance. Otherwise I wouldn't need to use this loop to "guess" at a solution and could find it exactly

Comment: Could you explain why it is impossible? If you have a matrix of points then finding the centroid should be as easy as `mean(allPoints)`

Comment: @JohnDodson what do you think of Alan's comment?

Comment: Because I only know all of those points in THAT coordinate system, not the other one. I have no way of transferring the centroid of that coordinate system to the other because I have no rotation matrix or transformation given to me between the two coordinate systems

Comment: @JohnDodson - the point is to subtract the centroid of each set from the respective set. Thus, the subtraction operation is independant of the other set of points. The result of the subtraction is two sets (in different coordinate systems) but both sets are centered around the (0,0,0) point of their respective coordinate system, thus  eliminating the translational element.

Comment: But when you find that centroid, what coordinates are you finding it in? One centroid will have coordinates x, y, z. The other will have x', y', z'. There is no relation between the two pairs of coordinates, therefore if we can't find a numerical answer for the translation.

Comment: Now that I think about it though, the translation doesn't even matter, I can just compare the orientation of the vectors and ignore that translational effect.

Comment: @JohnDodson subtracting the centroid does not find the translation (explicitly) it only eliminates its effect.

Comment: Yes ok I see what you are saying now, I can just ignore the effect thank you!

Comment: @JohnDodson once you find the rotation, I believe you will be able to reverse the "centering" process and find the translation...